# ¿Porqué descarga código HTML al principio de mi archivo CSV que genero en PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

tengo un problema estoy generando un archivo csv desde php y al momento de descargarlo y lo abro en excel por ejemplo aparece parte de mis etiquetas header HTML, adjunto mi código para que me puedan orientar de que estoy haciendo mal.

```
$filename = $NombrePais .$FechaDesde = $_GET['F_DESDE']."_".$FechaHasta . ".csv";

    // Encabezados que determinan la descarga del archivo y el nombre del archivo

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    // Un punto para referir la descarga
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // Los encabezados del archivo
    fputcsv($output, array('Fecha de Creación' , 'Usuario', 'Mensaje', 'Id Conversación'));

    $objConn = new DPConnection();
    $objConn->dpConnection($_dpHOST, $_dpPORT, $_dpDB, $_dpUS, $_dpCLA);
    $dpLink = $objConn->dpConnect();
    mysqli_query($dpLink, "SET NAMES utf8");
    $sqlInbox = "SELECT CASE WHEN m.id_from = $IdPagina THEN 'PriceSmart' ELSE 'Cliente'  END  as Usu , m.created_time as creatim, m.id_from, m.mensaje, m.conversacion_id_conversacion as idConver FROM mensaje";
    $ResultadoQuery = mysqli_query($dpLink, $sqlInbox);

    // loop en los registros, descargandolos
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ResultadoQuery)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

y este es el resultado que me muestra al principio, pero luego de que muestra toda esa cabecera desde la linea 160 en adelante muestra la información que necesito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano graciaaas!

Comment: Pareciera que tu generador de CSV está incluido en otro script PHP, que a su vez carga tu página HTML. Ese código que nos mostraste ¿es todo el contenido de tu script generador de CSV? ¿Puedes decirnos o mostrarnos cómo llamas a tu script que genera el CSV?

Comment: si, la verdad lo mando a llamar desde otro archivo, donde creo una vista de una tabla, haciendole referencia con un boton

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo que llames a este script generador de CSV en una nueva ventana: ya que lo que generará será un archivo, el navegador por sí solo hará las tareas predefinidas en él (abrirlo con Excel, o descargarlo, etc.)

Comment: Gracias, me Funcionó el abrirlo en una nueva ventana, pestaña, muchas gracias :)